# Best practices for designing a Custom Object. Experts please adivce

Tags: custom-object, bestpractice

I am trying to design a custom object which i'm wondering if there could be any best practices regarding object design. i.e.,

> Custom object design: Single record with multiple fields or Many
>   records with a single field. Which design is the best. Experts suggestions or thoughts if any please advice.

**Questions:**

1. Which of the following design is a best practice?
2. Which one is the best performer like indexing, ease of accessing the records, etc.
3. Which design would best suit for reporting purpose?
4. Which gives less data storage and storage efficient?

Please suggest.

**Custom Object Name:** SAP User Subscription

An user can subscribe to multiple events such as Bill Block, Credit Block, Delivery Block, etc. And they can unsubscribe from any of the event type.

**Design 1:**

Fields:

User Name : Lookup relationship
Event Type: Text
IsActive: Checkbox

So, the records would be stored in the custom object as follows,

[image]

**Design 2:**

User Name: Lookup Relationship
Event Type 1: Text
IsActiveEventType1: checkbox
Event Type 2: Text
IsActiveEventType2: checkbox
Event Type 3: Text
IsActiveEventType3: checkbox
Event Type 4: Text
IsActiveEventType4: checkbox

So, the records would be stored in the custom object as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The best solution would be to have an Event object and a many-to-many object (subscription?) which holds a lookup to the user and a lookup to the event. If an entry is in the subscription table then the user is subscribed to the event.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, but i want to use a custom event object and the custom user subscriptions object.

Comment: @BaskaranS That is exactly what I meant. Do that and it will work fine.